# Typescript Outputting "= !;" for undefined/nullable properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

### Issue

I've suddenly had my tsc start outputting the following within my js, this is throwing errors within my React application.

```
> 12 |         this.id = !;
```

This comes from assigning either of the following within one of my Classes:

```
public id?: number;
public id!: number;
```

The actual js output is happening within the class constructor (i.e. it's setting the values as exclamation marks which is obviously causing errors).

### My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "esnext",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "lib": [
    "dom",
    "es2016",
    "es2017"
  ],
  "importHelpers": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "downlevelIteration": true,
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "jsx": "preserve",
  "allowJs": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "strict": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "isolatedModules": true,
  "noEmit": true
},
"include": [ ... ],
"exclude": [ ... ]
```

}

### Attempts to fix

#### 1) Remove and re-transpile js

This has had no effect.

#### 2) Remove nullable/undefined properties

This removes the errors/offending js, but obviously I am now without the ability to declare these properties as such.

---

It's as if my tsconfig has suddenly gone haywire and decided to output nonsense.

Am I missing something glaring here?

---

Method called which sets properties from constructor:

```
private build(payload: BuilderPayload) {
    const allowed = this.getAttributes();
    [ ...Object.entries(payload) ].forEach(([ key, value ]:[ string, any ]) => {
        if (allowed.includes(key) && typeof value !== null) {
            this[key] = value;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: With `strictNullCheck`, `id: number` will not allow `null` or `undefined` anyway. Why do you do `id!: number`?

Comment: Also, can you post your class constructor? I don't seem to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Constructor calls the following method, I'm setting these dynamically by looping through the passed values, hence why they could be undefined at any point.    

[updated with method]